# WebView memory leak in windowScriptObject setValue:self forKey:?

Tags: cocoa, memory-leaks, webview, webkit, automatic-ref-counting

I have a Cocoa app with an embedded `WebView`. I set the window controller as accessible through JavaScript with the code below.

The problem is that the call to `setValue:self forKey:@"console"` seems to introduce a memory leak under ARC in a sense that the WebView and window controller are never released after the window was closed.

When I comment out the `setValue` line the WebView and controller are automatically released when the window is closed.

I tried `[self.webView.windowScriptObject removeWebScriptKey:@"console"]`, but that did not work either.

Code to add the JavaScript object in the window controller:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didClearWindowObject:(WebScriptObject *)windowObject
       forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {

    if (frame != self.webView.mainFrame) return;

    [self.webView.windowScriptObject setValue:self forKey:WELCOME_WINDOW_JS_NAME];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark,

You have identified the problem code. What is missing is that you aren't setting the key to nil when you release the window: `setValue: nil forKey: @"console"`. Do that and all will be well.

Andrew

Comment: This was insufficient for me.  Calling [self.webView close] resolved the leak.

Comment: [_webView close] is the way to go. Do not setValue:nil forKey:@"..." as it can crash if the webview is still loading. the -close method is documented and stops calling delegate methods, stop any loading and (undocumented but opensource) calls WebCore::ScriptController::clearScriptObjects()) which remove the scriptObjects correctly and release it.